# Programação Batch

Tags: cmd, batch, bat

Gostaria de fazer um batch que faça a seguinte contagem:

Ler o arquivo de origem:

```
7895537000011 
7895537000028 
7895537000035 
7895537000042 
7895537000059 
7895537000066
7895537000011 
7895537000011  
7895537000028 
7895537000028 
7895537000028
7895537000059 
7895537000059
```

Escreva assim num arquivo de destino:

```
7895537000011,3 
7895537000028,4 
7895537000035,1 
7895537000042,1 
7895537000059,3 
7895537000066,1
```

Somar as repetições e colocar na frente do item após uma virgula. Utilizo para fazer balanço de itens em loja.
Eu já consegui fazer um batch para incluir ",1" depois de cada código de barras usando este código:

```bat
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (Inventario_%loja%_%dia%-%mes%-%ano%_%hour%h%min%m%secs%s.inv) do (

echo %%a,1 >>C:\Inventario\Inventario_%loja%_%dia%-%mes%-%ano%_%hour%h%min%m%secs%s\Inventario_%loja%_%dia%-%mes%-%ano%_%hour%h%min%m%secs%s.log

)
```

Preciso diminuir o tamanho de linhas geradas por todos os códigos de barras e implementar uma contagem das ocorrências onde os códigos de barras se repetem.

Dessa forma:

> ***código de barras,ocorrências***
>
> ***`7895537000011,3`***

De forma que fique o total na frente do código.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: E ficou em dúvida no quê exatamente? Deu algum erro? Qual? Se não deu deu, gerou a saída inesperada? Qual saída gerou? Se nem conseguiu começar a fazer, o que você sabe de Batch? Por favor, edite a pergunta respondendo aos questionamentos pertinentes. Como é novo na comunidade, recomendo que faça o [tour].

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, eu editei.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é varrer o arquivo linha por linha e onde as linhas forem iguais, incrementa um contator e adiciona ele no final do arquivo.

```
#!/bin/bash

qnt_de_linhas=$(cat arquivo_origem | wc -l)
linhas_contadas=1
for (( i = 1; i <= qnt_de_linhas; i++ ))
do
    qnt_linhas_iguais=0
    linha=$(sort arquivo_origem | sed -n $i'p')
    for (( j = "$linhas_contadas"; j <= qnt_de_linhas; j++ ))
    do
        outra_linha=$(sort arquivo_origem | sed -n $j'p')
        if [ "$linha" == "$outra_linha" ]
        then
            let "qnt_linhas_iguais++"
        else
            continue
        fi
    done
    linhas_contadas=$(($linhas_contadas+$qnt_linhas_iguais))
    echo "$linha, $qnt_linhas_iguais" | grep -v ", 0" > arquivo_final
done
```

Esse é um pequeno script em bash(.sh) que pode te ajudar.

Sei que não é a linguagem que pediu, mas particularmente acho bash mais prático.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Gostei, porem preciso dele em Batch, para roda no CMD.

Comment: Refaz o script com os comandos certos... fiz em bash porq não conheço batch hahhah

Comment: Obrigado. Pela ajuda mesmo assim.

Answer (score 1):

A melhor solução nesse caso !!

so muda ***origem.txt*** e ***destino.txt*** no codigo para o nome do seus arquivos real !

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in (origem.txt) do (
  if defined ##%%a (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ('set ##%%a') do set /a tmp=%%b+1
    set "##%%a=!tmp!"
    ) else (
    set "##%%a=1"
    )
    )

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('set ##') do (
    set "$l=%%a"
    echo !$l:#=!,%%b
    )
)>destino.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Em powershell fica bem simples.

```
$Entrada = 'C:\entrada.txt'
$Saída = 'C:\saída.txt'

Get-Content -LiteralPath $Entrada |
    Group-Object |
    Select-Object -Property @{
        Label = 'Coluna'
        Expression = { $PSItem.Name + ',' + $PSItem.Count }
        } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Coluna' |
    Set-Content -LiteralPath $Saída -Force
```